# Reasons for syntactical difference in scripts

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

## EDIT

It is there in the second line that I indicate that the results are syntactically different but semantically identical.  My question is that ***why*** this may result from using the standard SQL Server Generate scripts.
The below is from two different copies of the database, where we generated the scripts. They are both from the same trigger.
Again, the question is **why** this might result from an automatic generation of scripts OR is this a matter of impossibility/improbability and therefore points directly towards manual intervention, i.e. editing of the triggers/scripts on purpose.

My most sincere apologies for not explaining the premise in a better manner earlier.

I'm trying to nail down an error at a client and I got a copy of their schema, triggers procs etc.

In some cases, I'm finding syntactical differences that yield the exact same results
e.g.

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE cd_units
        SET shift_expired_status = 0
    FROM inserted
    WHERE inserted.shift_start >= dbo.get_dts()
        AND inserted.unid = cd_units.unid
END
```

## VS

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE cd_units
        SET shift_expired_status = 0
FROM inserted
WHERE inserted.unid = cd_units.unid
    AND inserted.shift_start >= dbo.get_dts();
END
```

As you can see, the end result is the same, but functionally identical.

This should not be, unless someone is playing billy suggers with me, correct?  But this has already warranted a deeper investigation into the matter.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thank you sir, I apologize for not explaining the question better earlier, but you've just answered my question.

Comment: My apologies for not phrasing the question in a better manner, I thank you for your attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Generate Scripts command merely replicates exactly what's stored in the metadata about the object. If they come out with different results, that's because the object is different. Maybe someone has changed it, because they have misconceptions about how SQL Server might optimize based on the order of the clauses? We have no way to know how or why it has changed; we just know that SQL Server doesn't change it for you. You need to ask the people who are responsible for maintaining the database about why the object might have changed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm hesitant to answer, given that I'm not sure I entirely understand the question, but it does seem that you're confused about the two queries.

Whitespace differences apart (which don't affect the query in any way), the two queries are semantically identical. The only difference is the ordering of the conditions in the `WHERE` clause. The conditions themselves are the same, so you'll get the same results.

Comment: Thank you, I bettered my description of the problem and @AaronBertrand answered the question, but I thank you in every case, the fault for not explaining it better is mine entirely